# Are the two sentences equivalent?

Tags: sentence-structure, grammaticality, semantics

Statement 1:

```
Nach meinem Umzug musste ich mich überall ummelden. Das war anstrengend.
```

Statement 2:

```
Es war anstrengend, dass nach meinem Umzug ich mich überall ummelden musste.
```

or can statement 2 be also replaced with:

```
Es war anstrengend, dass nach meinem Umzug umzumelden.
```

On a similar note:

```
Man darf nicht ohne Visum in die USA einreisen. Das ist verboten.
```

and

```
Es ist verboten, in die USA ohne Visum einzureisen.
```

Comment: Statement 2 contains a small mistake, it should read "[...], dass **ich mich** nach meinem Umzug überall ummelden musste."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my understanding, statement 2 puts more emphasis on "es war anstrengend"; the subordinate clause is mainly an explanation what was exhausting.
In statement 1, both sentences have the same emphasis.

Your alternative is not correct:

> Es war anstrengend, <strike>dass nach meinem Umzug umzumelden.</strike>

You could use:

> Es war anstrengend, mich nach meinem Umzug überall umzumelden.

In your second example, a changed order sounds/looks more natural to me, probably because "ohne Visum" is the most important part.

> Es ist verboten, ohne Visum in die USA einzureisen.